# Find if a logo exists inside of an image with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, ocr

I am trying to see if there is a way on a nodeJS server to process an image and see if it contains another image. For example:

Image 1: An image of lets say a laptop

```
exmaple: http://amasoncomputers.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/hp-630.jpg
```

Image 2: And image of a company logo

```
example: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/29/HP_New_Logo_2D.svg/2000px-HP_New_Logo_2D.svg.png
```

I have scrolled through lines and lines of OCR and OpenCV stuff, but I do not understand C or C++ that well. Is there a node module I am missing, or is this just not possible as of yet with the V8 javascript runtime?

Comment: It's surely possible, but this is what big companies are using billions of dollars on, recognizing objects and people in images etc.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cloudsight and https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-to-text

Comment: Thanks, not sure how comfortable I am with uploading to Cloudsight, rather do all the processing on my server.

Comment: https://github.com/peterbraden/node-opencv#face-detection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finding an in image inside an image but is quite hard using a free open source library but finding a text inside an image is much more possible accessible using an OCR library. If your logo embebbed the brand as text, or any specific word it should solve your problem.

a node module exists to wrapp tesseract, a popular free OCR library
 https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-tesseract